# Export key and value of dictionary as name and contents of files in python

Tags: python

I want to create a folder based on current date, in which I create files with names are  keys of dictionary and the contents of each file is the value of dictionary .
Can someone help me ?

```
import datetime
import time, datetime, os
import os 

list_init = {'10': [xxxxxx], '25': [yyyyyy], '28': [zzzzzz]}
mylist = list(list_init.keys())
today = datetime.date.today()  
todaystr = today.isoformat()   
os.mkdir(todaystr)
os.chdir(todaystr)
for item in mylist:
   with open('%s.txt'%item,'a') as in_file:
      in_file.write('  ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over your dictionary using `items()` which would give you easy access to it's keys (`k`) and values (`v`). Also open files with `'w'` parameter since you want to create files and ignore possible existing content.

```
import datetime
import os

my_dict = {'10': "xxxxxx", '25': "yyyyyy", '28': "zzzzzz"}

today = datetime.date.today()  
todaystr = today.isoformat()   
os.mkdir(todaystr)
os.chdir(todaystr)

for k, v in my_dict.items():
    with open(f'{k}.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(v)
```

**Created files:**

```
.
├── 2019-12-12
│   ├── 10.txt -> xxxxxx
│   ├── 25.txt -> yyyyyy
│   └── 28.txt -> zzzzzz
└── create_dir.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor updates in your code:

```
for k, v in list_init.items():
   with open('%s.txt'%k,'a') as in_file:
      in_file.write(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for your requirement:

```
import datetime
import time, datetime, os
import os

list_init = {'10': "xxxxxx", '25': "yyyyyy", '28': "zzzzzz"}
mylist = list(list_init.keys())
today = datetime.date.today()
todaystr = today.isoformat()
os.mkdir(todaystr)
os.chdir(todaystr)

for key in list_init.keys():
    for item in list_init[key]:
        with open('%s.txt'%key,'a') as in_file:
            in_file.write(item)
```